# gdb break after input

Tags: debugging, gdb

i'm trying to learn gdb. i wrote a simple program that just listen to input via fgets and compare it to a 'password'.

how can i use gdb to halt the program and see the comparisson?

if i halt execution with `ctrl+c` during the input i get:

```
   #7  0xf7e771ea in _IO_fgets (buf=0xffffd7f0 "T\332\377", <incomplete sequence \367>, n=256, fp=0xf7fa9440) at iofgets.c:58
   #8  0x080486bc in check_password ()
   #9  0x08048949 in main ()
```

Is there any way i can show the code listing of `check_password`? if i trype `list` it shows me fgets'...

any way i can step out of `fgets`?

what would you do from here?

Answer (score 0):

If you compile using debug mode (on gcc, this is -g), you can set a breakpoint in gdb at the line where you execute. Once in gdb, enter the command `break x` where x is a line number. You can break on the line after check_password(), if your variable is in scope, or within.  Or, if you break before, you can step through the code line by line.

Comment: i explicityly compiled in gcc without debug info for the exceciser. (also, i can't upvote until i have 15 reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

`disassemble 0x080486bc` did the trick!

i got the call to fgets and put a breakpoint after it.

But please, contribute with what else you would do to 'crack' this simple string comparisson :)

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint where you want the code to halt?

Comment: @CodyGray yeah that helped to get out of fgets when restarting the program. but knowing how to "stepout" would have been cool for the cases where i can't restart to get to the buggy point. for the record, i set `b check_password` and restarted the program

Comment: Well, I don't use GDB and never have. But a quick Google search should be able to find out how to step out of a function using the debugger.